I need a SELECT that selects fields consisting of consecutive digits
I need a SELECT that selects records consisting of consecutive digits.
In a T-SQL select I need to select all records in the column 'phone' where all digits are consecutive ascending or descending but if there is a non-consecutive digit, it does not detect it.
Example:
1234567 is detected by the select.
1234568 is NOT detected by the select because there is no 7 between 6 and 8.
876543 is detected by the select.
1245689 is not detected by the select because all the digits are not directly consecutive.
Thank you!

Is this a homework/interview question? What have you tried so far?

@DavidG yeah, looks suspicious, "real" questions usually never have such good examples of expected and actual data

"I need" isn't a question. What are you asking? What have you tried? Why isn't it working? What about the wealth of information already about there didn't you understand?

I must admit, however, this looks like validation that should occur in the application layer, not the SQL later. T-SQL is a terrible language choice for this task.

This is pretty easy to accomplish:
SELECT  *
,   CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE('1234567890', phone, '')) <> 10 OR LEN(REPLACE('1234567890', REVERSE(phone), '')) <> 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS detected
FROM    (
    
    VALUES  (1234567, 1)
    ,   (1234568, 0)
    ,   (876543, 1)
    ,   (1245689, 0)
    ) x (phone, expected)

You take the 1234...0 string and replace it with the phone number. If replace "succeeds", it means that phone has consecuitive numbers. To handle descending numbers, you also test for REVERSE of the phone number.
You can adapt the code if 0 should be handled in some other way.
Output:



phone
expected
detected




1234567
1
1


1234568
0
0


876543
1
1


1245689
0
0




Use charindex() to find phone no in '1234567890 0987654321':
select *
from tablename
where charindex(phone, '1234567890 0987654321') > 0

Or, if phone column data type is integer:
where charindex(cast(phone as varchar(11)), '1234567890 0987654321') > 0

Demo at: https://dbfiddle.uk/1nqfaJda (incl. siggemannen's query)
